# how to add a simple new UIView in a window based application programmatically in iphone?

Tags: iphone, macos

i want to add a new View Which Contain Anything in a window based application programmatically could someone tell me a step by step process to do this and also how to add controls on that new view programmatically.

i have created a new view and added a label in that now how do i add a button and i want to change the text of label when i clcik on that button?
anyone help me?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In most cases you use a ViewController. But it is possible to add a UIView directy to the window. Perhaps you can explain more what you want to do.

```
UIView* view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,480)];
UILabel* label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
[label setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18]];
[label setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
[label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[label setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[label setText:@"Hello"];
[view addSubview:label];
[window addSubview:view];
```

You can get a referens to the window (if you don't already have one) with

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
```

Comment: plz tell me where i write the code. do i need to add a new uiview subclass?

Comment: You would do this in the RootViewController. If you're not used to doing this, you're better off using Interface Builder.

Comment: If you want to build an application from scratch with the windowsbased template. 

I would start by coding a viewcontroller, then build upp the views subviews in the "loadView" function. Then i would add it to the window in the applicationDidFinishLaunching function in the appdelegate... But as Alex says, any reason not to use the IB?

Comment: Also, my example was done without taking memory management into account. You would need to call [label release] and [view release]... Just to be clear.